# How to match the width to the actual screen

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

How can I maximize the width of this program that I get on someone's tutorial.

here's the code:

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    width = (w < h)?w:h;
    height = width;         //for now square mazes
    lineWidth = 1;          //for now 1 pixel wide walls
    cellWidth = (width - ((float)mazeSizeX*lineWidth)) / mazeSizeX;
    totalCellWidth = cellWidth+lineWidth;
    cellHeight = (height - ((float)mazeSizeY*lineWidth)) / mazeSizeY;
    totalCellHeight = cellHeight+lineWidth;
    gold.setTextSize(cellHeight*0.75f);
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
```

any answers will be appreciated thanks !

Comment: Is this android or something? Do at least tell us what platform you are working on!

Comment: Im sorry. Yes im using android eclipse kepler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got an answer to this one :)

```
//new value
    height = width+(width/2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
int width = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width;
int height = GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height;
this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = width;
this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = height;
this.graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
this.graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

it is my given answer proved by question's man. thanks

Reference: [Maximizing the width and height of the Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670052/maximizing-the-width-and-height-of-the-screen/23687133#23687133).

Comment: do i suppose to create a new class GraphicsDevice?